# jQuery EasyUI dataGrid save when enter pressed

Tags: jquery, datagrid, onkeyup, jquery-easyui

I have a EasyUI propertyGrid (which inherits dataGrid) with a few rows. 
I need that when user is editing a text field, when enter is pressed, editing is finished and onAfterEdit is called. EasyUI does not do this by default! Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with treegrid, so i think you can use this code with propertyGrid also:

```
    onDblClickRow: function(row){
            if (editingId != undefined){
                $('#arbol_eui').treegrid('select', editingId);
                return;
            }

            if (row){
                editingId = row.id;
                pos = row.id;
                $('#arbol_eui').treegrid('beginEdit', editingId);
            }
            var ed = $(this).treegrid('getEditor',
                                     {index:editingId,field:'peso'});

            $(ed.target).focus().select().bind('keyup', function(e) 
            {
                var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
                  //Trigger code to save row
                                      //This executes onAfterEdit event code
                  var t = $('#arbol_eui'); //My treegrid selector
                              t.treegrid('endEdit', editingId);
                              editingId = undefined; //editingId is a global var

                }
            });
        },
```

The key is to bind jquery event 'keyup' to the textbox editor for the cell at the 'onDblClickRow' event that also starts editing the row

Good luck

Comment: I came up with key solution but still after editing one row and pressing enter, the row was not editable anymore unless user clicked on another row or focused outside of the propertyEditor. By looking at your code, I learned to use onClickRow to initiate editing programmatically, which solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I also used propertygrid('acceptChanges') right after ('endEdit') which makes the changes permanent in the given row.

Answer (score -1):

Try the datagrid-cellediting extension, it adds some functionality like this